# How is UTF-16 converting string?

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, utf-16

```
b'\x14\xfeh\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00'
```

I understand that UTF-16 uses 16 bits but what confuses me the most is that 16 bits is two characters, so why do I see a long line of hexadecimal characters? It should be like for example "ee" these are 16 bits 8 bits in the character.

Can someone explain to me why I see a long line of hexadecimals?

How does the utf-16 converts strings ???? What is the theory behind it ??

Answer (score 2):

Because of the notation, I guess you're using Python.
In Python, the `b'...'` notation is used for [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) objects.

When `str` or `bytes` objects are represented in the source code or on the terminal, all characters that represent a printable ASCII character (***roughly*** all values from 32 to 127), are shown as that character. All other characters are escaped using the `\xx` notation, where `xx` is the hexadecimal number.
This is why you see a strange mix of printable characters and escape codes.

Note that you can escape printable characters as well: `b'\x41'` is the same as `b'A'`, since the hexadecimal number 41 (65 in decimal) is the letter `A` in ASCII. However, the Python interpreter doesn't do this by default.

**How does UTF-16 work?**

UTF-16 simply uses 16 bits (= 2 bytes) for every character <sup>1</sup>.
There are however two variants of ordering the bytes, called *little endian* and *big endian*. To decode UTF-16 data, you have to know which encoding was used. Sometimes UTF-16 data starts with a Byte Order Mark (BOM), which is a special character that can be used to determine the byte ordering.

Your Python string `b'\x14\xfeh\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00'` consists of 24 bytes, so 12 UTF-16 characters.
I guess your first byte is corrupted somehow, because it results in a strange character. It probably should have been `\xFF` instead of `\x14`, because when the data starts with the two bytes `\xff\xfe`, this is a signal that the bytes are stored in Little Endian format. (See this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) on Wikipedia).

Finally, decoding the data in Python is very simple:

```py
b'\xff\xfeh\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00w\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00'.decode('utf-16')
```

output:

```py
'hello world'
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *This is not entirely true, because some special characters are actually represented using a combination of two UTF-16 characters, but you should probably ignore that for now. For (much) more information about UTF-16, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).*